# How to change size of AdMob ad

Tags: java, android, admob

Recently I have added AdMob to my app and I would like to resize the AdMmob ad.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get a different dimension ad to show up, or are you trying to change the size of an existing ad dimension?

Comment: I am just trying to get a certain dimensions for ads shown.

Comment: Are you asking how to request specific ad sizes from AdMob, or how actually change the size of an ad. Do you want to stretch the ad, or make it smaller? Ads generally come in specific sizes (Example: 300x250, 320x50, etc.), and while you can choose which of those sizes you want, you can't really change the size of an ad you've already fetched.